# React Native, how to find out default value for each inbuilt component style property?

Tags: react-native

E.g. How to find out the default `fontSize` of `Text` component or the default `flex` value for `View` component.

React devtools is only showing styles that has been explicitly set in my code.

Also checked the docs e.g. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view-style-props but no style property lists a default value.

Comment: you can search component in "Node module"  directory and can check default prop value in component file

Comment: @thegoodguy can you give an example of the path to find the component file say of a `View`

Answer (score 0):

Actually the default fontSize is the fontsize of android or ios device you are using. You can change this default font size in your device settings.

If you want to know you default font size you can check with [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info) . As it provides you a function names as getFontScale() which provides you the font ratio